# WPF Web browser alternative

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, chromium-embedded

I have a WPF application that used `webBrowser` control and that uses `IE7` internally that becomes painful when I try to add any javascript library because `IE7` doesn't support new features.

I tried to change browser render mode by using

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
```

but it was not only breaking design but was looking different in `IE11` than in `WPF` `WebBrowser` control in windows App.

I can't use [updating registry as in MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) because many of user don't have permission to update registries and I can't reach all the users to fix it.

I tried to find any alternative to replace in-built `WebBrowser` control and I found [Awesomium](https://awesomium.codeplex.com/), [CEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef) and [CEFSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) but they don't allow using `IE` but stick to `Chromium`. Not all my users have `Chromium` but `IE11` is common in all of their computers.

So, the real question is, is there any browser control that will replace existing `WPF WebBrowser` control and use `IE` of higher version? Or is there any other solution to make existing `WebBrowser` control to use `IE` with version of my choice? May be `IE9+`

Comment: I thought CEFSharp bundled everything necessary - I don't think it relies on Chrome/Chromium being installed on the target PC?

Comment: `CefSharp` doesn't require `Chrome` to be installed. You cannot use `CEF` directly as it only provides a `C/C++ API`, you'll need to look at `CefSharp`, `CefGlue` or `ChromiumFx` as the three `.Net wrappers` for `CEF`. `CefSharp` requires `VC++` which you can package with your app, see the `FAQ`

Answer (score -4):

Try using WindowsFormsHost

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.Misc_controls.WindowsFormsHostSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
        Title="WindowsFormsHostSample" Height="350" Width="450">
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost Name="wfhSample">
            <WindowsFormsHost.Child>
                <wf:WebBrowser DocumentTitleChanged="wbWinForms_DocumentTitleChanged" />
            </WindowsFormsHost.Child>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

from this example...

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-windowsformshost-control/

Comment: You'll be stuck with the same underlying WebBrowser tech/problems.